# How to find $\partial\chi^2/\partial b$ when $\chi^2=\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{D(x_i)-a-b(x_i)^2}{\sigma_i^2} $?

Tags: partial-derivative

How do I find How to find  $\partial\chi^2/\partial b$ when $\chi^2=\sum_{i=1}^N\dfrac{D(x_i)-a-b(x_i)^2}{\sigma_i^2} $?

My attempt:
        \begin{align*}
    \dfrac{\partial}{\partial b}\sum_{i=1}^N\dfrac{D(x_i)-a-b(x_i)^2}{\sigma_i^2} &= \dfrac{\partial}{\partial b}\Bigg[\sum_{i=1}^N\dfrac{D(x_i)-a}{\sigma_i^2}-\sum_{i=1}^N\dfrac{b(x_i)^2}{\sigma_i^2}\Bigg]\\
    &=  \dfrac{\partial}{\partial b}\Bigg[\sum_{i=1}^N\dfrac{D(x_i)-a}{\sigma_i^2}\Bigg]-\dfrac{\partial}{\partial b}\Bigg[\sum_{i=1}^N\dfrac{b(x_i)^2}{\sigma_i^2}\Bigg]\\
    &= 0-\dfrac{\partial}{\partial b}\Bigg[\sum_{i=1}^N\dfrac{b(x_i)^2}{\sigma_i^2}\Bigg]\\
    &= -\dfrac{\partial}{\partial b}\Bigg[\dfrac{b(x_1)^2}{\sigma_1^2}+\dfrac{b(x_2)^2}{\sigma_2^2}+\cdots+\dfrac{b(x_N)^2}{\sigma_N^2}\Bigg]\\
    &= -\dfrac{\partial}{\partial b}\Bigg[\dfrac{b(x_1)^2}{\sigma_1^2}\Bigg]+\dfrac{\partial}{\partial b}\Bigg[\dfrac{b(x_2)^2}{\sigma_2^2}\Bigg]+\cdots+\dfrac{\partial}{\partial b}\Bigg[\dfrac{b(x_N)^2}{\sigma_N^2}\Bigg]\\
    &= -\dfrac{1}{\sigma_1^2}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial b}\Bigg[b(x_1)^2\Bigg]-\dfrac{1}{\sigma_2^2}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial b}\Bigg[b(x_2)^2\Bigg]-\cdots-\dfrac{1}{\sigma_N^2}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial b}\Bigg[b(x_N)^2\Bigg]\\
    &= -\dfrac{1}{\sigma_1^2}\cdot2\cdot b(x_1)-\dfrac{1}{\sigma_2^2}\cdot2\cdot b(x_2)-\cdots-\dfrac{1}{\sigma_N^2}\cdot2\cdot b(x_N)\\
    &= -\Bigg[\dfrac{2}{\sigma_1^2}\cdot b(x_1)+\dfrac{2}{\sigma_2^2}\cdot b(x_2)+\cdots+\dfrac{2}{\sigma_N^2}\cdot b(x_N)\Bigg]\\
    &= -\sum_{i=1}^N\dfrac{2b(x_i)}{\sigma_1^2}
\end{align*}

Is this correct?

EDIT: I previously asked [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3014606/how-to-find-partial-chi2-partial-a-where-chi2-sum-i-1n-dfracdx-i) question. But the fact that $b$ is a function and changes with each different $x_i$ confuses me.

Comment: Does "$b(x)^2$" mean "$(b)\cdot (x^2)$", or is $b$ a function so that it means "$(b(x))^2$"? If $b$ is a constant, then by linearity the derivative is just $-\sum_i x_i^2/\sigma_i^2$.

Comment: @MPW $b(x_i)$ is a function.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer thanks to @MPW 's comment.

\begin{align*}
            \dfrac{\partial}{\partial b}\sum_{i=1}^N\dfrac{D(x_i)-a-b(x_i)^2}{\sigma_i^2} &= \dfrac{\partial}{\partial b}\Bigg[\sum_{i=1}^N\dfrac{D(x_i)-a}{\sigma_i^2}-\sum_{i=1}^N\dfrac{b(x_i)^2}{\sigma_i^2}\Bigg]\\
            &=  \dfrac{\partial}{\partial b}\Bigg[\sum_{i=1}^N\dfrac{D(x_i)-a}{\sigma_i^2}\Bigg]-\dfrac{\partial}{\partial b}\Bigg[\sum_{i=1}^N\dfrac{b(x_i)^2}{\sigma_i^2}\Bigg]\\
            &= 0-\dfrac{\partial}{\partial b}\Bigg[\sum_{i=1}^N\dfrac{b(x_i)^2}{\sigma_i^2}\Bigg]\\
            &= -\dfrac{\partial}{\partial b}\Bigg[\dfrac{b(x_1)^2}{\sigma_1^2}+\dfrac{b(x_2)^2}{\sigma_2^2}+\cdots+\dfrac{b(x_N)^2}{\sigma_N^2}\Bigg]\\
            &= -\dfrac{\partial}{\partial b}\Bigg[\dfrac{b(x_1)^2}{\sigma_1^2}\Bigg]-\dfrac{\partial}{\partial b}\Bigg[\dfrac{b(x_2)^2}{\sigma_2^2}\Bigg]-\cdots-\dfrac{\partial}{\partial b}\Bigg[\dfrac{b(x_N)^2}{\sigma_N^2}\Bigg]\\
            &= -\dfrac{1}{\sigma_1^2}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial b}\Bigg[b(x_1)^2\Bigg]-\dfrac{1}{\sigma_2^2}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial b}\Bigg[b(x_2)^2\Bigg]-\cdots-\dfrac{1}{\sigma_N^2}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial b}\Bigg[b(x_N)^2\Bigg]\\
            &= -\dfrac{(x_1)^2}{\sigma_1^2}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial b}[b]-\dfrac{(x_2)^2}{\sigma_2^2}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial b}[b]-\cdots-\dfrac{(x_N)^2}{\sigma_N^2}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial b}[b]\\
            &= -\dfrac{(x_1)^2}{\sigma_1^2}\cdot1-\dfrac{(x_2)^2}{\sigma_2^2}\cdot1-\cdots-\dfrac{(x_N)^2}{\sigma_N^2}\cdot1\\
            &= -\Bigg[\dfrac{(x_1)^2}{\sigma_1^2}+\dfrac{(x_2)^2}{\sigma_2^2}+\cdots+\dfrac{(x_N)^2}{\sigma_N^2}\Bigg]\\
            &= -\sum_{i=1}^N\dfrac{(x_i)^2}{\sigma_i^2}
        \end{align*}